# How to redirect user when clicking an option in a select list?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm kicking my self for not being able to do this. But I've tried almost everything. I simply want to redirect a user to a specific page when they click an option in my option value list. Here's my current code (which should explain my question better):

```
<select name="test_redirect">
<option value="1" onclick="document.location = 'http://localhost/shop?item=1';">Item 1</option>
<option value="2" onclick="document.location = 'http://localhost/shop?item=2';">Item 2</option>
<option value="3" onclick="document.location = 'http://localhost/shop?item=3';">Item 3</option>
</select>
```

I've also tried onChange as well. Same result. Can some one please help me with this? Thank you guys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
document.querySelectorAll("[name=test_redirect]")[0].addEventListener('change',
   function () {
       window.location = "http://localhost/shop?item=" + this.value;
   });
```

This depends on a relatively new browser (with `querySelectorAll` and `addEventListener`), but the principle's the same.  `click` doesn't get triggered on options, so you have to go with `change` on the `<select>`.  Might as well consolidate the code a bit too.

http://jsfiddle.net/5n5ZE/

Comment: Thank you very much. This is exactly what I needed :) props to you!

Answer (score 1):

```
<select id="test_redirect">
<option value="1">Item  1</option>
<option value="2">Item 2</option>
<option value="3">Item 3</option>
</select>
```

**javascript**

```
var val = document.getElementById("test_redirect").value;
window.location.href = "http://localhost/shop?item=" + val;
```

**jquery**

```
$("#test_redirect").change(function(){

    var val = $(this).val();
    window.location.href = "http://localhost/shop?item=" + val;

 });
```

Comment: He doesn't have any jQuery code or the jQuery tag; jQuery <> JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

try this (give the link of the page in `value` of each option)

```
<select name="test_redirect" onchange="window.location.href=this.form.test_redirect.options[this.form.test_redirect.selectedIndex].value">
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind the event handler to the `<select>` and not the individual options:

```
<select name="test_redirect" onchange="location.assign('http://localhost/shop?item=' + this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)">
<option value="1">Item 1</option>
<option value="2">Item 2</option>
<option value="3">Item 3</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will save you lines :

```
<select onchange="location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">
<option value="1">Item  1</option>
<option value="2">Item 2</option>
<option value="3">Item 3</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<select name="test_redirect" onchange="location.href='http://localhost/shop?item='+this.value">
<option value="1">Item 1</option>
<option value="2">Item 2</option>
<option value="3">Item 3</option>
</select>
```